# Trending query Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Right now I have a subquery to get the count of payments for the current month and then getting the 4 products with the highest payment_count. This query works fine but I'm wondering if there's a more simple way to do the same since its getting difficult to read.

```
$latestPayments = DB::table('payments')
            ->select('product_id', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as payments_count'))
            ->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->groupBy('product_id');

$trendingProducts = DB::table('products')
             ->joinSub($latestPayments, 'latest_payments', function ($join) {
                 $join->on('products.id', '=', 'latest_payments.product_id');
             })->orderBy('payments_count', 'DESC')->take(4)->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

This did it!

```
$trendingProducts = Product::withCount(['payments' => function($query) { 
    $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month); 
}])->orderBy('payments_count', 'DESC')->take(4)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eloquent query with relational database you can do like this:

```php
$latestPaymentWithTrendingProduct = App\Payment::with(['products', function($product) {
  $product->orderBy('payments_count', 'DESC')->take(4);
}])->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))->get()->groupBy('product_id');
```

This will lessen the code but still do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. I changed a few things and it works. Here's the code

$trendingProducts = Product::withCount(['payments' => function($query) {
                $query->whereMonth('created_at', Carbon::now()->month);
            }])->orderBy('payments_count', 'DESC')->take(4)->get();

Comment: nice you can play with it.